# Какие есть варианты упрощения кода?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я пытался написать код, чтобы при команде `>usercheck` бот выводил сообщение, где показывает информацию о пользователе (не через упоминания, а через НикНейм) через эмбед.
Можно ли как-то упростить и сделать так, чтоб бот находил где-то записанный ник и давал по нему информацию, записанную в коде?

```
client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def checkuser_user(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('Please, wait')
    PREFIX = '>'
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'User info')

    emb.add_field(name = '{}Bans'.format(PREFIX),value = '0')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}Kicks'.format(PREFIX),value = '0')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}Warns'.format(PREFIX),value = '1/3')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}Ban reason: '.format(PREFIX),value = 'None')
    emb.add_field(name = '{}Role history'.format(PREFIX),value = 'Verify.')
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: Сохраняйте в базе данных и из нее берите инфу юзеров

Comment: С помощью SQLite3?

Comment: Я бы выбрал через sqlite

Comment: Если лень в БД можно через словарь, но если бота будут много использовать то словарь с таким об'ємом не справится.